# Determine if mathematical expressions are functions and get range

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Which of the following mathematical expressions are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? If $f$ is a function, give its range.

I am a little confused how to determine if they are functions or not, I had a new baby on this day of class so I am a little lost. Thanks for any help!

1 - $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x}$

2 - $f(x,y) = 1/(x^2-4)$

3 - $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2}$

[Image of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6AQJ.png)

Comment: Are there any limitations on the values $x$ can accept in any of the functions?

Comment: @abiessu I think the values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$, from the first line. At least it seems like so.

Comment: @abiessu the first line is the actual question they are asking... that is everything I am given :-/

Comment: I'm also a little confused. Why you write $f(x,y)$ for a function of one variable? And what have to do the tag ''discrete-mathematics'' with your question? And, more important, what have you tried?

Comment: @BrandonTurpy By the last comment I meant the first sentence. They ask which of the functions given are actually function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. As of what I understand, function number one is *not* from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I just copied the question as is. I tagged discrete-mathmatics because the class I am in is called Discrete Math Structures... Sounds like it may not be well worded... which would be a good reason why I am confused. Im pretty sure #2 is not a function, because the #2 does not map to a number, since you can not divide by 0

Comment: @OFRBG: I was not asking if the domains or co-domains were specified.  I was asking if the OP could identify whether, for example, $x=-1$ could be used in the first function...

Comment: @abiessu Sorry :(  I didn't catch the tone.

Comment: @OFRBG: no worries.  I get told all the time that I have a strange way of wording things, and my meaning is often lost in the words I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te function 1) is not $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ because, for $x<0$, $\sqrt{x}$ is not a real number.

The function 2) is not $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ because for $x=\pm 2$ we have a division by $0$ that is not defined.

the function 3) is $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, and we have $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, so its range is the set of all non negative real numbers.